# Windows - robocopy kill server service and server stop respond to smb - how to real time sync folders over lan without samba?

Tags: crash, samba, robocopy

I have nightmare in company. New server 2019 with all patches. I use Robocopy to sync files to backup server. Robocopy kill smb "server service" several times per day, no any event log. Windows 10 clients cant access shares. Only solution is to restart server. Can even restart server service, which stuck in stopping state. I like robocopy because can have log for history. But, cant anymore use this stupid SMB protocol. Can reproduce error if sync to remote server. Than remote server 2012 r2 stops respond to smb shares.
Exactly symptoms like in this big topic:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/ja-JP/e9567167-22db-4b8c-9f96-a08b97d507f9/server-2012-r2-file-server-stops-responding-to-smb-connections?forum=winserverfiles
Any help?
Goodsync can detect moved,renamed files but is very expensive and dont know if it uses smb.

Answer (score 0):

If copying file to a backup server, you generally do not need real-time replication unless do you want the two server be in a cluster of sort - ie: having a stand-by server ready to take connection in the case the first server goes down.

That said, the right tool for a semi-synchronous file share replication between Windows server is [DFSR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dfsr/dfsr-overview). It is not a silver bullet, but I suggest you to investigate it to understand if it fit your case.

Comment: dfsr wont support long path over 260 char depth. This is problem in my environment because workers is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this tool Gs RichCopy 360 Enterprise, it does not use SMB copy and it offers RTA or TRA, This uses a single tcp port to copy and made especially for wan copying and small files too .  It does not rely on SMB and alleviates the pressure on the server.
I recall it was affordable (did not have a hard time with finance to purchase it, else I would have remembered )